# Print.format() function not working in Python

Tags: python, printing, scikit-learn

I am getting used with datasets from the scikit-learn and I am currently using the iris dataset (dataset for classification of different species of iris).
When I try to visualize the values describing the flowers features using print adding with this code:

`from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset=load_iris()
print("Keys of the iris dataset:\n".format(iris_dataset['feature_names']))`

I just obtain this output from the console:

*Keys of the iris dataset:*

On the other hand, if I use the print function without "format" with this line:

`print("Keys of the iris dataset:\n",(iris_dataset['feature_names']))`

I obtain at least an output:

*('Keys of the iris dataset:\n', ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'])*

This happens with every section of the dataset I try to display, it seems a problem with the function format(), does anyone have any suggestion for solving it and correctly visualize the formatted output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string doesn't have anything to interpolate.
You need to use a `{}` somewhere for each parameters you want put into the string, like this:

```
>>> print("Keys of the iris dataset: {}\n".format(iris_dataset['feature_names'])
)
Keys of the iris dataset: ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal lengt
h (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the curly braces `{}` which are essentially placeholders. They will be replaced with the variable(s) specified in the  `str.format` function. Please try this:

```
print("Keys of the iris dataset:\n{}".format(iris_dataset['feature_names']))
```

This will give you:

```
Keys of the iris dataset:
['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']
```

Please check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or one of the many tutorials on `Python string format()` on the web.